# Update XML value using value from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to update a value in a column of type XML with a value from another column in the same table. The code below does not update the value and returns no error.

DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.customer
(customer_id INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,customer_q1_value INT NOT NULL
,customer_details XML NOT NULL)

INSERT dbo.customer
SELECT 8, '<Customer><Status>Active</Status><CustomerValue>6</CustomerValue><Category>173</Category></Customer>'
UNION ALL
SELECT 14, '<Customer><Status>Active</Status><CustomerValue>5</CustomerValue><Category>173</Category></Customer>'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '<Customer><Status>Active</Status><CustomerValue>5</CustomerValue><Category>173</Category></Customer>'
UNION ALL
SELECT 7, '<Customer><Status>Active</Status><CustomerValue>7</CustomerValue><Category>173</Category></Customer>'
```

XML:

```xml
<Customer>
    <Status>Active</Status>
    <CustomerValue>6</CustomerValue>
    <Category>173</Category>
</Customer>
```

```
UPDATE customer
SET customer_details.modify('replace value of(/Customer/CustomerValue/text())[1] with (sql:column("customer_q1_value"))')
```

Comment: Can you give us a CREATE TABLE statement and some INSERTS of sample data, so we can run the queries and see what's wrong? Example schema and data really helps us help you. Simplify it down to it's bare essence, and anonymize any table or column names, so you can get a pure demonstration of the problem.

Comment: thanks, I've added the CREATE and INSERT sections above.

Comment: Using the DDL provided, your UPDATE query worked just fine : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27df3/3

Comment: Do you still have any issues? If not, you might place your own `UPDATE`command with  a short comment as answer and accept this as "best answer" in order to close this question.

Comment: It still wouldn't work with my production table, I have dropped and recreated the table and it works fine now.

Comment: I had to use insert query to first fill dummy value and then replace
UPDATE customer 
SET customer_details.modify('insert text{"dummy"} into
(/Customer/CustomerValue/text())[1]')